# @Autowired used with Constructor

Tags: constructor, spring-data-jpa, autowired

This has been confusing me for long. I have been wondering how can I work with both of them conveniently.

I have truly tumbled into this today:

```
@Slf4j
@Service
public abstract class ServiceParserAbstract {
    private KubeServiceRetriever kubeServiceRetriever;

    public ServiceParserAbstract initialize(KubeServiceRetriever kubeServiceRetriever) {
        this.kubeServiceRetriever = kubeServiceRetriever;
        return this;
    }
}
```

I tried to use `@Autowired` in the abstract class directly but it failed with **NPE** when trying to access.

And then I thought perhaps I can put these `@Autowired` up to the **descendants** as follows and then using `@PostConstruct` to access it.

```
@Component
public class Service8Parser extends ServiceParserAbstract {
    @Autowired
    private KubeServiceRetriever kubeServiceRetriever;

    @PostConstruct
    public ServiceParserAbstract getInstance() {
        return initialize(kubeServiceRetriever);
    }
}


public class ServiceParserFactory {
    public static Optional<ServiceParserAbstract> getParser(ServiceVersionEnum versionEnum) {
        switch (versionEnum) {
            case VERSION_8:
                return Optional.of(new Service8Parser().getInstance());
            case VERSION_8_EARLIER:
                return Optional.of(new Service8EarlierParser());
            default:
                break;
        }
        return Optional.empty();
    }
}
```

Still I failed and have no idea what's going on.

Why I just have to use `@Autowired` in all these attempts. Because I do no know how to use **JPA** when not using `@Autowired`.

```
public class KubeServiceRetriever {
    @Autowired
    private EnvironmentUsageRepository environmentUsageRepository;
}
```

For now, I think I have two ways to go:

1. working with both `@Autowired` and original primitive `Constructor` to create instance;
2. manage repository using other methods instead of `@Autowired`.

Can anyone please share some ideas or clues.

**Thank you very much!**

Answer (score 0):

Using `@Autowired` all along the way, it can work.

```
@Component
public class ServiceParserFactory {
    @Autowired
    private Service8Parser service8Parser;

    public Optional<ServiceParserAbstract> getParser(ServiceVersionEnum versionEnum) {
        switch (versionEnum) {
            case VERSION_8:
                return Optional.of(service8Parser);
            default:
                break;
        }
        return Optional.empty();
    }
}

@Slf4j
@Service
public abstract class ServiceParserAbstract {
    @Autowired
    private KubeServiceRetriever kubeServiceRetriever;
}

@Service
public class Service8Parser extends ServiceParserAbstract {
}

@Component
public class ServiceParser {
    @Autowired
    private ServiceParserFactory serviceParserFactory;
    private ServiceParserAbstract serviceParser;
    public ServiceDo parseService(Long envId, String serviceName) throws RetrieverException {
        serviceParser = serviceParserFactory.getParser(ServiceVersionEnum.VERSION_8).get();
        return serviceParser.parseSingleService(envId, serviceName);
    }
}
```